# AVFoundation equivalent of ffmpeg CRF

Tags: objective-c, swift, video, avfoundation, video-encoding

In ffmpeg you can use thee Constant Rate Factor (CRF) instead of setting an average bit rate when transcoding from one codec into h264. Is there an equivalent way of not setting the bit rate but rather a quality level when transcoding video with AVFoundation?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right, couldn't you set your AVCaptureSession

```
AVCaptureSessionPresetLow
```

or

```
AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. I was referring to transcoding media into h264, not capturing in h264. I edited the question.